# Celery - retrieving children from group identifier

Tags: python, redis, celery

Is it possible to retrieve a list of tasks using only a group identifier?

```py
from celery import group

def f1():
    task_group = group(task1, task2)
    return task_group().id

def f2(group_id):
    pass
    # TODO: return task1.id and task2.id
```

`GroupResult(id=f1()).children` returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```py
from celery import group

def f1():
    task_group = group(task1, task2)
    task_group.save()
    return task_group().id

def f2(group_id):
    task_group = GroupResult.restore(id=group_id)
    return task_group.children
```